# Parse datetime-range or duration given a partial datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Suppose I am given a partial datetime string. I wish to obtain the datetime it represents, and what was the resolution of the given datetime.

For example:

- `"2021-01-06 12"` ->  `2021-01-06 12:00:00.000000` and `"hour"`
- `"2020-03"` -> `2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000` and `"month"`
- `"2020-03-01"` -> `2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000` and `"day"`

The idea is to use a given partial datetime-string as a time-range specification. Meaning that instead of writing `"All of March, 2020"`, just write `"2020-03"`.

The question can be reduced to an answer with the `pandas` framework, though given a partial string like in the above examples, `pd.Timestamp(...)` parses it well (e.g. `pd.Timestamp("2020-03") == pd.Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000')`).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: It seems that the internal function [`pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1b9be34545664f58481abdce9bf0c1bb7b07f0ae/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L327) returns what I want. Does anyone know how can I access it (not accessible using `from pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing import parse_datetime_string_with_reso`)?

Comment: you would need to use `pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_time_string` which internally calls the `parse_datetime_string_with_reso`

Comment: @AsishM. Damn I'm stupid. Didn't see that it returns the resolution as well. Thanks! I'll make sure that it works. Post it as an answer. –

Comment: @AsishM. It does indeed do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing specifically this section of the question:

> EDIT: It seems that the internal function pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso returns what I want. Does anyone know how can I access it (not accessible using from pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing import parse_datetime_string_with_reso)?

You can use `from pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing import parse_time_string` which internally calls `parse_datetime_string_with_reso` and also returns the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`dateutil` has a good parser that allows the input string to have missing parts:

```python
from dateutil import parser


dates = ["2021-01-06 12", "2020-03", "2020-03-01"]

for date in dates:
    if len(date.split('-')) <= 2:
        # If day is missing, resulting day will be the same as
        # the current day of month instead of '01'.
        date += '-01'
    parsed = parser.parse(date)
    print(parsed)
```

output:

```
2021-01-06 12:00:00
2020-03-01 00:00:00
2020-03-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not wish it to just to handle the missing parts - that I have. I wish it to also return the resolution of the parsed time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/
A python module for locating dates inside string.

Comment: That's not the same as what I want. Thank you anyway.